# compare string with array values

Tags: java, android

```
ArrayList<String> stylistidArr = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> durationArr = new ArrayList<>();
Integer duration = null;
stylistIDArray = differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedStylistIdArray();
durationArray = differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedDurArray();
for (int i = 0; i < stylistIDArray.size(); i++) {
    stylistidArr = stylistIDArray.get(i);
    durationArr = durationArray.get(i);
    if (stylistidArr.contains(stylistid)) {
        duration = Integer.parseInt(durationArr.get(i));
        Log.d("duration", String.valueOf(duration));
    }
}
```

I am having two arrays one is integer array and another one is string array also i am having one string i want to compare the string with all strings in an array if any of the array values matches with string i want to get integer value from integer array in that position.
EX 
`ArrayList<string> strvalue =(a,b,c,d,e),ArrayList<Integer>intValues=(1,2,3,4.5)` and `String str=c;` .i want to get integer value 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple 'for' will do:

```
public Integer find(String searchedKey, List<String> keys, List<Integer> values) {
  for (int i = 0; i < keys.size() && i < values.size(); i++) {
    if (searchedKey.equals(keys.get(i))) {
      return values.get(i);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
keys.add("a");
keys.add("b");
keys.add("c");
keys.add("d");
keys.add("e");

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(1);
values.add(2);
values.add(3);
values.add(4);
values.add(5);

Integer value = find("c", keys, values);
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<stylistIDArray.size() && i< durationArray.size();i++){
                                   if(stylistid.equals(stylistIDArray.get(i))){
                                       durArr=(durationArray.get(i));
                                   }

                                }

Comment: Ah... you are NOT using it as a function. You'll need to use `break` when you find it. Otherwise it always end up being null. Alternatively, I would recommend placing this logic into a function (as my example) since it's easier to read and to debug.

Comment: thank you its working now instead of using array i used arrayoFarraylist that's why i got null.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < stylistIDArray.size(); i++) {
stylistidArr = stylistIDArray.get(i);
durationArr = durationArray.get(i);
if(stylistidArr.equals(str){
// compares the ith element with "c"
k=values.get(i);
break;}
}
```

Use the value of k as needed.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < stylistIDArray.size(); i++) {
                                stylistidArr = stylistIDArray.get(i);
                                durationArr = durationArray.get(i);
                                if(stylistidArr.equals(stylistid)){
                                    strDuration=durationArr.get(i);
// compares the ith element with "c"
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

Comment: Its giving null